# DB2 backup error

Tags: db2

We've a DB2 10.5 instance running on Windows 2008 R2 server. This instance has 10 databases. We have been encountering the following error while performing an offline backup of one of the databases. The error occurs every 5 mins for more than an hour and at some point it is able to get an exclusive connection and backup this database

```
SQL1035N  The operation failed because the specified database cannot 
      be connected to in the mode requested.
```

We tried the following:

```
db2 quiesce instance with restricted access and force connections
db2 deactivate database
db2 backup 
db2 activate
db2 unquiesce instance
```

Before this, we also tried a force application all and db2terminate but was in vain. Has anyone encountered such and error before? Appreciate your thoughts and thanks for your time.

Regards,

Comment: It just means that someone (most likely the instance owner) has managed to connect to the database even after the quiesce. I see that you have no error checking (to verify that each individual step succeeds). This is faulty, not robust.  When the Db2-backup fails you should issue (in a script) `db2 list applications show detail` and identify each connection - with the aim of ensuring that each auth-id is *not* the DB2-instance owner (the account that runs the Db2 service in Windows) unless the connection is internal from Db2.  Why not switch to online backups to avoid this kind of issue ?

Comment: Thanks Mao. We're also considering online backups and at the same time trying to understand the cause of this issue. I'll update this thread after I check the list of active connections.

Comment: The cause is simple: you have something connecting to the database before the offline backup (i.e. something is implicitly activating the database between the deactivate and quiesce).  You can also use the `db2pd `tool with the `-db ... -connections` immediately before the backup, and after the backup fails. Check if you have externally scheduled jobs, or app-servers that repeatedly connect, or external monitoring/alerting tools that are getting in the way. But usually in a corporate environment the only sensible approach is online-backups.